# table division text dissapears after validation is run on submit

Tags: html, asp.net, validation, razor

In my razor page I've got several check boxes arranged in a table. I've got some other @Html.EditorFor elements that are required inputs. When I submit, and the validations are run, the page refreshes with the eoor messages and the text next to my check boxes in the table disappears. What's up with that?

My checkboxes are made with @Html.CheckBoxFor

I'm not using any special stylings or class attributes or anything right now.

Comment: I found that this is because I'm using the label text from the model. If I use hard-coded text it stays. Not sure how to keep the label text though if it comes from the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. When the form is posted, you will lose all of that data provided you do not resend it back into your view. In your controller, you need to return the model along with the view. Without seeing your code, I can't give a specific answer but it should look something like this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomethingWithFormPostData(Model yourModel)
{
    //Do whatever you need to do.
    return PartialView("_yourView", model);
}
```

Alternatively, I like to have a method in my controllers to I use for the sole purpose of populating a page. If you have something like that, you can refer back to that sending the model as a routevalue in this way:

```
public ActionResult DoSomethingWithFormPostData(Model yourModel)
{
    //Do whatever you need to do.
    return RedirectToAction("_yourView", "YourController", model);
}
```

Comment: This was the fix, the part of the model that was used for my labels wasn't returned back after checking the validations.